# How can I make my responsive navbar take overlay on top of my contents when opened?

Tags: html, css

I'm new when it comes to creating responsive items, navbar to be exact. I currently have a problem where my navbar doesn't appear on top of the contents when opened. You can see it open but it just lays underneath the contents. How can I make it appear on top of the contents? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
  color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

label.logo {
  color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

label.logo span {
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(227, 227, 227);
  width: 80%;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
  transition: .5s;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34);
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(34, 34, 34);
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.checkbtn {
  display: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {
  label.logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  nav ul {
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34);
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 858px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 10px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #check:checked~ul {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  label.logo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 25px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.single-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
  <label class="logo span"><span>Lorem</span></label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-area">
    <div class="single-box">
      <div class="img-area"></div>
      <div class="img-text">
        <span class="header-text"><strong>Lorem</strong></span>
        <p>
          Si enim aute te doctrina. Varias senserit ubi quis amet nam admodum id multos laborum. Sed culpa eram hic vidisse, velit et ea sunt deserunt.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-box">
      <div class="img-area"></div>
      <div class="img-text">
        <span class="header-text"><strong>Lorem</strong></span>
        <p>
          Si enim aute te doctrina. Varias senserit ubi quis amet nam admodum id multos laborum. Sed culpa eram hic vidisse, velit et ea sunt deserunt.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-box">
      <div class="img-area"></div>
      <div class="img-text">
        <span class="header-text"><strong>Lorem</strong></span>
        <p>
          Si enim aute te doctrina. Varias senserit ubi quis amet nam admodum id multos laborum. Sed culpa eram hic vidisse, velit et ea sunt deserunt.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for z-index?

Comment: Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add 'position: fixed' or absolute to nav. And use z-index: 2.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Just for future references, what does z-index do?

Comment: Great! Z-index layers the elements. To use it, you need a position: absolute, fixed or relative. Z-index: 1 could be a background. Z-index: 2 could be the element in the foreground. You don't always need to use it. But sometimes it comes in handy. May I ask you mark my answer as the answer? I'm pretty new to stack overflow so it would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, I did mark your answer down as the correct one. I'm new to stack overflow also.